# Codeigniter - How to set encryption key in config.php

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, codeigniter-3

I have read through the documentation of Codeigniter on how to use the encryption library. However, I have doubt in initializing it, I am not sure where should I call the library and create the key. I have tried initializing the key in config.php as shown below but I am getting error message: CI_Controller not found in core/Codeigniter.php.

```
$CI =& get_instance();
// Get a hex-encoded representation of the key:
$key = bin2hex($CI->encryption->create_key(16));
$config['encryption_key'] = hex2bin($key);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you change it via controller ? you can do this

```
function changeEncryption_key(){
    $this->load->library('encryption');
    $key = $this->encryption->create_key(16);
    $key = bin2hex($this->encryption->create_key(16));
    $config['encryption_key'] = hex2bin($key);
}
```

Comment: I will have to encrypt and decrypt using the same key right? It shouldn't be called every time updating the key.

Comment: then why you don't generate it somewhere then copy-paste to it ?

Comment: and check this https://forum.codeigniter.com/thread-68741-post-346461.html#pid346461